# Visual Studio 2008 intellisense gone

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I'm using vs2008, asp.net website.

Having all sorts of issues with vs2008, latest is that I have no intellisense.. none at all.  Also, the 2 dropdowns at the top of my .aspx and .aspx.vb pages (i.e. in VS code view) have also gone (so I've lost the shortcut to add a page_load snippet, etc..

why oh why could this be happening? 'build web site' completes successfully with no errors.

cheers :D

Answer (score 2):

1. Try restarting VS2008
2. Try rebooting your machine
3. Try reinstalling VS2008

Comment: *groan* looks like I'm at option 3 :(

Answer (score 1):

The following actions can help determine what the problem with your Intellisense is:

1. Create a new project to see if Intellisense returns. If it does, it's a project issue.
2. Run devenv /resetsettings to reset any settings that might have corrupted VS.
3. Disable add-ins to see if any of 
   these are the problem. Reenable 
   them one at a time until you find 
   the one that causes the problem.
4. Create a new user account and run it
   from there. If it doesn't run, it's
   a corrupted user profile.
5. Reboot Windows to safe mode and see
   if it's an environment problem

Comment: thanks pete, I'll get working through those... no luck so far though to point 4..